# Finding the "orthogonal" map of a given 1d map

Tags: dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be entire. Let $z:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be such that it holds
$$z(t+1) = f(z(t)).$$
If we choose carefully $z$ can be constructed to be also entire. This is done usually by choosing an unstable direction of a fixed point and then propagate analyticity using $f$.

So my question is the following: Given $f$ can we find $g$ such that
$$z(t+i) = g(z(t))?$$
Is this something known?
Does this $g$ depend on $z$? Is it unique?
What can we say about $g$ without knowing $z$ explicitly?

The obvious property of $g$ is that it "commutes" with $f$, i.e. $f\circ g = g\circ f$. What else can we say?

One way to look at the function $z$ is as a way to conjugate $f$ to the map $t\mapsto t+1$. So $g$ is conjugated to $t\mapsto t+i$ which is orthogonal to $t\mapsto t+1$, hence the name.

I am interested in this because it changes fixed points that are centres to nodes.